# Autowire problems with Spring 3.2 and Jersey 2.4

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I'm trying to upgrade a system that's using Spring 3.2 and Jersey from Jersey version 1.17 to Jersey version 2.4.  I'm running into an annoying problem with @Autowired where Jersey basically complains it cannot find the bean for a given (generic) type.

We have a base class (`BaseService<T>`) for database-backed services that provides a basic CRUD-style interface (get, save, delete).  We also have a base class for the REST resources that looks similar to this:

```
public abstract class BaseResource<S extends BaseService<T>>
{
    protected S service;

    // ... common functions used by BaseService descendants ...

    @Autowired
    public void setBaseService(S baseService)
    {
        this.service = baseService;
    }
}
```

And then we have a number of concrete classes that inherit from `BaseResource`, provide their unique logic, etc.  Under Jersey 1.17 this works fine.

After upgrading my environment to Jersey 2.4 and including the jersey-spring3 project, I get different behavior.  During service startup I can verify that the `setBaseService()` routine gets called by Spring and the supplied parameter is not null.  However when a client makes a call and an actual REST resource is executed, Jersey logs the following warning

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.AutowiredInjectResolver getBeanFromSpringContext
WARNING: No beans found. Resolution failed for type S.
```

This actually results in Jersey passing a null parameter to the `setBaseService()` routine, which of course causes NPEs.  Now I can work around the null parameter with a check, but I'd like to know why Jersey is having this problem and how I can avoid it.

Interesting fact is that I have another REST resource that does not inherit from `BaseResource` but does contain its own `@Autowired` `setService()` routine.  This one works perfectly fine; it gets called correctly by Spring at startup and correctly by Jersey with a non-null parameter upon each call.  It's just the generic-based setter that has the problem.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show that other REST resource? Are generics involved?

Comment: There are no generics involved in that other resource.  It simply has an `@Autowired` routine like `setService(FooService fooService)`, and it works fine.

Comment: If I make that other resource and its service part of the hierarchy then I run into the same Jersey problem.  So I think there's a bug in Jersey related to either generics or inheritance here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.
Add the following dependency: jersey-spring3
The above allows Spring DI support into JAX-RS classes with spring xml.
If you are using Maven, add the following into your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>`
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>`
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure we had that and still had the problem, although that might have been with version 2.4 and not 2.4.1.  We worked around the problem in a different (and semi-complicated) manner.  This newer version of Jersey almost seems as though it is trying to out-Spring Spring; we've had to work around a few things that Jersey has done.